# Automatic Line break for a column using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to have a line break for one column using phpexcel. The Nth column starting from N3, I need to have automatic line break for this column so that the entire row shifts downwards. I tried the following code. but it is not working.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('N3:N'.$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow())->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(50);
```

The column N3:Nj is having a long text which is fetched by a query result. setWrapText is not giving the desired result. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I must restrict the column width of Nth column to 50. If more text comes, it must go to the next line in the same row, increasing the row width.

Comment: If you cannot achieve it wit PHPExcel, can you add newlines to the text on server-side?